# What's the difference between "add" and "set" in updateExpression which in dynamodb updateItem and how to use them?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use updateExpression to update string or number value, I have two questions about that.

1) I know set works for that, but I don't know how to add "if_not_exists" in my code, my current code is

`"updateSpec.withUpdateExpression(" set #attribute = :r")"`

2)Can I use add for that?  in document it says, "The ADD action only supports Number and set data types. In addition, ADD can only be used on top-level attributes, not nested attributes."
what does top level attributes means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ConditionExpression along with the UpdateItemSpec. An attribute is said to be top level if it is not embedded within another attribute.
Refer here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html

Comment: so do like this    .withConditionExpression("attribute_not_exists(#attribute)")？